# What is causing this unknown error in my code?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, append

I am trying to make an app where whenever a certain button is clicked, the value of a score variable (whatever its value is at the time) is appended to an array. I made a NavigationLink that brings you to another view where it presents all the scores. However, whenever I click the NavigationLink to see the scores, it crashes. The error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range".

Here is the code for the button:

```
Button(action: {
    gameTracker += 1
    counter += 1
    gameScores.append(scoreTracker)
            
    roundTracker = 1
    scoreTracker = 0
}
```

Here is the code for the view which is meant to show up after the NavigationLink is clicked:

```
struct scoreView: View {
    @Binding var scoreTracker: Int
    @Binding var gameTracker: Int
    @Binding var gameScores: [Any]
    @Binding var counter: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Scores: ")
        
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<counter) {
                Text("Game \($0): \(String(describing: gameScores[counter])) ")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: The fact that you have `gameScores` defined as `[Any]` is a sign that there is something structurally suspicious with your code. You should probably know what the type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, you should use `$0` instead `counter`:

```
struct scoreView: View {
@Binding var scoreTracker: Int
@Binding var gameTracker: Int
@Binding var gameScores: [Any]
@Binding var counter: Int
var body: some View {
    Text("Scores: ")
    
VStack {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<counter) {
            Text("Game \($0): \(String(describing: gameScores[$0])) ") // <<: Here!
            }
        }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for a while now. What was wrong with the counter?

Comment: @Krish Think of `ForEach` similar to a regular `for` loop - you are iterating over a range, and you get the value for each iteration. Same here, where `$0` is (implicitly) the value you get from each iteration of the `ForEach`. Using `counter` was incorrect because it was always more than `gameScores.count`, hence index out of range error.